# How To Download django-mssql On Windows

Tags: django, django-mssql

I can't download django-mssql from Google Code there doesn't seem to be a direct download link and the svn wont work for me.

Anybody know a direct download link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the latest release from [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/) using `pip install django-mssql` or `easy_install django-mssql`. If you aren't using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) already then I would recommend you start.

Comment: How about somthing for Python 2.5?

Comment: `easy_install` can install for a particular Python version if you have multiple installed using `easy_install-2.5`. It's best to use `virtualenv` http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/ along with `pip` to keep your Python versions and packages separated.

Answer (score 0):

The [source](https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/src) is under a mercurial repository.  If you have a mercurial client installed, you can check it out with the following command:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/ django-mssql
```

Comment: I looked up Mercurial Repository Apps and ended downloading TortoiseSVN great SVN app, but still cant access googlecode